# Proving that a set is open topologically.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Munkres' topology 13.1:
Let X be a topological space. Let $A \subseteq X$. For all $x \in A$, there exists open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq A$. Prove that $A$ is open.

First attempt: Let $x \in A$. Then $x \in U_x \subseteq A$. Therefore, $\bigcup U_x \subseteq A$. But since $U_{x}$ is open in $X$, and $A$ is the union of open sets, then by the definition of topology, $A$ is contained in the collection $\tau$.

**edit**: $\bigcup U_x  \subseteq A$ since $U_{x} \subseteq A$ by hypothesis. Similarly, all $a \in A$ are contained in $U_{a}$ and thus in $\bigcup U_x $. Thus, $A=\bigcup U_x $ and is the union of open sets. Consequently, $A$ is open since it is the union of open sets.

**General comments regarding this type of proof are also welcome, topology is brand new to me, and I'm studying it independently.

***I cleaned up the notation.

Comment: $A$ is a union of open sets...

Comment: @Bernard I was trying (maybe incorrectly) to show this. What is a better way to get this idea across/ is it not clear that this is what I'm attempting?

Comment: It's almost correct now, except for a typo in a formula, and a problem in notation: how do you distinguish between the $U$s for different $x$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Let $x \in A$. Then $x \in U_x \subseteq A$. Therefore, $\bigcup_{U_x} \subseteq A$.

Firstly you need to say $\bigcup_x U_x$ rather than $\bigcup_{U_x}$.  Other than that your approach is alright so far.

To prove that $A\subseteq \bigcup_x U_x$, observe that $x\in U_x\subseteq A$ is true of **every** $x\in A$. So for every $x\in A$ there is some $U_x$ containing $x$; therefore every $x\in A$ is a member of the union; therefore $A$ is a subset of the union.  But the union is also a subset of $A$, so the union is $A$.

Finally, why is the union open?  Here the answer is simply that the union of every set of open sets is open.

Comment: The axiom of choice can easily be avoided here: instead of picking just one open $U_x$ satisfying $x\in U_x\subseteq A$, one can pick all of them. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I actually didn't thin carefully about your final point. Is there a straightforward proof for the fact that the union of open sets is open?

Comment: That is part of the definition of a topology. It wouldn't qualify as a topology otherwise.  In some particular spaces one may wish to prove that a particular family of subsets actually is a topology, and then one would have to _prove_ that it is closed under unions.  But here it is _given_, when we say we're working in a topological space. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Okay, I thought that was true. I thought you were implying that something else was necessary. Is the idea of openness characterized by anything outside of a "by definition" in topological space? For example, in analysis it's that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $[x-\delta,x+\delta] \in I$ for all $x \in I$.

Comment: @AndresMejia : In some particular topological spaces one does that.  For example, in metric spaces one defines "basic" open sets as open balls and then one defines open sets as unions of basic open sets, or alternatively one says a set $A$ is open if for every $x\in A$ there is some open ball centered at $x$ that is a subset of $A$. In linearly ordered sets one defines basic open sets as open intervals and again defines open sets as unions of basic open sets.  However, if all one knows about a space is that it's a topological space, then it's just by definition. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

This attempt does not work. How exactly do you conclude that $A$ is open? $\tau$ is not the set of *all* subsets of $X$.

Also, you don't seem to be using "$\{x\}$" for anything.

HINT: What are some ways you can show a set is open? Think in terms of building it out of "simpler" sets . . .

Comment: Does it not suffice to show that if $A$ is in the collection $\tau$, then it is open?

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, since $\tau$ is *by definition* the set of open sets. But you **haven't** shown this.

Comment: I see, but then if you show that it is the union of open sets, it is open?

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes - but in your argument, you have not done this. Why is $\{x\}$ open? (In fact, it usually *won't* be.)

Comment: I edited it, that was a failure of notation.

Comment: I see, I get it what you were saying, it is actually equivalent to the union of open sets. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x\in A$ let $U_x$ be open with $x\in U_x\subseteq A$. Then $A=\bigcup _{x\in A}U_x$. A union of open sets is open by definition of topology.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is the union of its points, and since every $U$ is contained in A and there is one $U_x$ for every $x$, than $A$ is the union (maybe infinite) of open sets each one "centered" in a different $x$ and so it is an open set.

Comment: You invoked the axiom of choice a bit needlessly.

Comment: Really? Where did I use it?

Comment: umm maybe not. in these proofs its tempting to "take a U_x for every x" and do something with it.

Comment: Yes, you can take a $U_x$ for every $x$, maybe it is the same sometimes. We know there is one for every $x$, and we know we can make infinite union. Is this axiom of choice?

Comment: "take" and "choose" mean the same thing. taking A as the union of all open sets contained in it will work. taking A as the union of all the U_x's will invoke choice.

Comment: mmmh so you just say something like "make the union of every open subset of $A$, than you are sure that every $x \in A$ is contained thanks to the hypothesys of $U_x$?

Comment: yeah. I have an intuitive idea of the difference between "choose a U_x for each x and do something with it" and "there is a U_x for each x" and the former takes choice and the latter doesn't, but I'm not firm enough on this to understand it. the axiom of choice is a bit esoteric to work with formally.

Comment: It's wierd that you don't need an axiom in order to make the union of every single subset, but you need it in order to just make the union of some of them!

Comment: As Michael Hardy says in his comment following his answer: For each $x\in A$ we can define $V_x=\cup \{ \text {open } U : x\in U\subset A\}$ without the Axiom of Choice. Obviously the hypothesis on $A$ implies $\cup \{V_x : x\in A\}=A.$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof isn't correct - you seem to be assuming that $\{x\}$ is open (in $\tau$), which is not true in general. Remember that you're only guaranteed that the union of a collection of *open* sets is open.

Instead, to each $x\in A$, associate the open set $U_x$ with $x\in U_x\subseteq A$. Can you show that $\bigcup_{x\in A} U_x = A$?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a topology includes the requirement that any union of open sets be open. Can you write $A$ as a union of given open sets?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I don't understand your proof. It looks like you are saying that since $A = \cup_{x\in A} \{x\}$, we have that $A$ is open. This is not a valid argument, as the singleton sets $\{x\}$ need not be open. You need to relate $A$ to open sets somehow, and the only tool you are given are the sets $U$. (Edit: It looks like it might just have been your notation that confused me, and you did something along the lines of the below).

I would do it as follows: Let $x\in A$ be arbitrary. By our hypothesis, there exists an open set $U_x$, such that $x\in U_x\subseteq A$. I claim that

$$\bigcup_{x\in A} U_x = A.$$

Indeed, since each $U_x$ is contained in $A$, the left hand side is certainly contained in the right hand side. Vice versa, $x\in A$ is contained in $U_x$, so the right hand side is also contained in the left hand side.

By definition of a topology, the union of open sets is open. But the left hand side is such a union, and since it is equal to $A$, it must be open.